# Center the last element or the 2 last element

Tags: html, css

I have 5 div and I want the last 2 or the last one centered. Because when I resize the window I can have 4div at the top and 1 at the bottom or 3 at the top and 2 at the bottom.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xyvmebg1/) for better explanation

```css
.button-video{
 width:220px;
 height:50px;
 background-color: #234CA5;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:5px 10px;
}
.button-video a{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
}
.button-video span{
 font-size:14px;
 color:white;
    padding-left:25%;
 line-height: 50px;
}

.play{
 position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:10px;
    top:10px;
    left:5px;
    width:40px;
    height:30px;
}
.triangle{
 margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:15px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 16px solid #234CA5;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}
.triangle:hover{
 cursor:pointer;
}
.button-video:hover .triangle{
    border-left: 16px solid #D3222A;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-video">
      <a href="../docs/interactif_2005/TRIXELL2005.mpg"></a>
       <div class="play">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
       </div>
       <span>Présentation TRIXELL 05</span>
      </div>
      <div class="button-video">
      <a href="../../4_1_technical_product_manager/documents/P4600-P4700-P4800.avi"></a>
       <div class="play">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
       </div>
       <span>P4600 - P4700 - P4800</span>
      </div>
      <div class="button-video">
      <a href="../../4_1_technical_product_manager/documents/P3543pR-P4343RF.avi"></a>
       <div class="play">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
       </div>
       <span>P3543pR - P4343RF</span>
      </div>
      <div class="button-video">
      <a href="../docs/liens/4600%20Flash.lnk"></a>
       <div class="play">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
       </div>
       <span>Animation PIXIUM 4600</span>
      </div>
      <div class="button-video">
      <a href="../docs/liens/4700%204800%20Flash.lnk"></a>
       <div class="play">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
       </div>
       <span>Animation 4700 - 4800</span>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap buttons within container with text-align center, remove floating and display inline block button-video

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="button-video">
        <a href="../docs/interactif_2005/TRIXELL2005.mpg"></a>
        <div class="play">
            <div class="triangle"></div>
        </div>
        <span>Présentation TRIXELL 05</span>
    </div>
    <div class="button-video">
        <a href="../../4_1_technical_product_manager/documents/P4600-P4700-P4800.avi"></a>
        <div class="play">
            <div class="triangle"></div>
        </div>
        <span>P4600 - P4700 - P4800</span>
    </div>
    <div class="button-video">
        <a href="../../4_1_technical_product_manager/documents/P3543pR-P4343RF.avi"></a>
        <div class="play">
            <div class="triangle"></div>
        </div>
        <span>P3543pR - P4343RF</span>
    </div>
    <div class="button-video">
        <a href="../docs/liens/4600%20Flash.lnk"></a>
        <div class="play">
            <div class="triangle"></div>
        </div>
        <span>Animation PIXIUM 4600</span>
    </div>
    <div class="button-video">
        <a href="../docs/liens/4700%204800%20Flash.lnk"></a>
        <div class="play">
            <div class="triangle"></div>
        </div>
        <span>Animation 4700 - 4800</span>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.container{
    text-align: center;
}

.button-video{
    width:220px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: #234CA5;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:5px 10px;
}
.button-video a{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.button-video span{
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;
    padding-left:25%;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.play{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:10px;
    top:10px;
    left:5px;
    width:40px;
    height:30px;
}
.triangle{
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:15px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 16px solid #234CA5;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}
.triangle:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.button-video:hover .triangle{
    border-left: 16px solid #D3222A;
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nk398pcp/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flexible box method for easily achieving that layout on resize.

Wrap all the elements inside a container. `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` will center the last single or two items.

[**Updated JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/xyvmebg1/2/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.button-video {
  width: 220px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #234CA5;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}
.button-video a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.button-video span {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 25%;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.play {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
}
.triangle {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 16px solid #234CA5;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}
.triangle:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button-video:hover .triangle {
  border-left: 16px solid #D3222A;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button-video">
    <a href="../docs/interactif_2005/TRIXELL2005.mpg"></a>
    <div class="play">
      <div class="triangle"></div>
    </div>
    <span>Présentation TRIXELL 05</span>
  </div>
  <div class="button-video">
    <a href="../../4_1_technical_product_manager/documents/P4600-P4700-P4800.avi"></a>
    <div class="play">
      <div class="triangle"></div>
    </div>
    <span>P4600 - P4700 - P4800</span>
  </div>
  <div class="button-video">
    <a href="../../4_1_technical_product_manager/documents/P3543pR-P4343RF.avi"></a>
    <div class="play">
      <div class="triangle"></div>
    </div>
    <span>P3543pR - P4343RF</span>
  </div>
  <div class="button-video">
    <a href="../docs/liens/4600%20Flash.lnk"></a>
    <div class="play">
      <div class="triangle"></div>
    </div>
    <span>Animation PIXIUM 4600</span>
  </div>
  <div class="button-video">
    <a href="../docs/liens/4700%204800%20Flash.lnk"></a>
    <div class="play">
      <div class="triangle"></div>
    </div>
    <span>Animation 4700 - 4800</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it works but this isn't support by IE9 and I need to, any idea ?

Comment: Not with flexbox. But you can check the fallback here using CSS tables: http://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/qbzhJ